# Initialize a subclass of NSManagedObject

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject, afnetworking-2

I have a question about CoreData and NSManagedObject.

I receive a NSDictionary in my ClientRESTClass (I use AFNetworking 2.0) so I have a Json data in this NSDictionary.

For this object type I use a my protocol with two methods that these objects must implement:

```
- encodeFromJson //(instance to JSON)
- decodeFromJson //(from json I create an instance)
```

Now I have a myObj as subclass of NSManageObject that implements this protocol.

1) In the  `decodeFromJson` how can I to generate an instance of  myObj? Is necessary to use in this point a context? Is possible to use a simple init?

2) At this level I receive data from server an I create instance of these object. I pass this instance to the caller and he will decide whether to save the object or if you do not save it in CoreData. 
So, If I have to use a contex, how can I discard objects that I placed in the context?

Answer (score 1):

You should not create an NSManagedObject directly, you should use the `NSNSEntityDescription's` `insertNewObjectForEntityForName` -- see: [Apple Docs.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/Reference/NSManagedObject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001171-BBCFJIEE)